# Comparing IDs in two arrays

Tags: objective-c

I have two arrays that I need to compare if their IDs are equal. This is how I am currently doing it:

```
PFQuery *earnedQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"EarnedAchievement"];
[earnedQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[earnedQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    for (Achievement *achievement in allAchievements) {

        for (PFObject *earnedAchievement in objects) {

            if ([achievement.id isEqualToString:earnedAchievement[@"achievmentId"]]) {

                //user has earned this achievement
                achievement.earned = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                achievement.earnedDate = earnedAchievement[@"earnedOn"];

            }

        }

    }

    [context save:&error];

}];
```

Is there a better or more efficient way to do this outside of the two `for` in loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing we can do to improve the efficiency of this code is to remember to check for an error and make sure that the returned `objects` array returns *anything* before we do anything.  Generally, code from Apple libraries would guarantee our `objects` array to be empty if there were any sort of error, but some libraries don't make that guarantee.

We can also store our `allAchievements` locally as an `NSDictionary` rather than an array.  If `allAchievements` is an `NSDictionary`, our code looks something more like this:

```
[earnedQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    for (PFObject *earnedAchievement in objects) {
        Achievement *achievement = allAchievements[earnedAchievement[@"achievmentId"]];
        if (achievement) {
            achievement.earned = @YES;
            achievement.earnedDate = earnedAchievement[@"earnedOn"];
        }
    }
    [context save:&error];
}];
```

Now we eliminate the nested loop.  And we only run through the outer loop once per `earnedAchievement` (which may be zero times).

Also, keep in mind that everything within the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` is executing in the background.

---

*Some other comments...*

I would eliminate the use of magic strings.  Define all of your keys as constants somewhere.  This serves multiple purposes.

1. If we *ever* decide to actually change the key, it's changed everywhere all at once.
2. Typing magic strings is prone to typos, where as using a variable won't compile if we've made a typo (unless we typo into another variable name).
3. Typing magic strings won't auto-complete (which makes typos more likely, see point 2), but constant variables will.

Comment: This is good information, I will give this a shot.  What do you mean by magic strings?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an extremely large number of achievements, I would recommend looking into a hash table, it will give you constant time lookups instead of the linear time lookups you are using now.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Code Review. Please add more context to your answer, such as an example. That will help more that just a simple two-sentence answer.

Comment: I disagree @MannyMeng. It may be a short answer, but seems to be very good advice. Also, this is Code *Review*. Answers are under no obligation to contain any code. Code snippets should be considered a bonus, although they do tend to make good answers *great*.

Comment: @RubberDuck That was what I was trying to say...